# Deep scan using reflection - Is there a better way?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am working on a way to find all properties which have a certain attribute. This needs to work not just on a single class, but recursively within. In the below example (which works), I have a recursive method which is able to do this, but I am not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it.

In this scenario, I am looking for string properties with an attribute [Localizable] and replacing the string with a localized text.

Any advise to improve the Localize method or indeed the overall approach is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
public class C1 
{   
    [Localizable]   
    public string L1 { get; set; }   

    public C2[] C2Array { get; set; } 
}

public class C2 
{   
    [Localizable]   
    public string L2 { get; set; }      

    public C3 C3 { get; set; }  

    public List<C3> C3List { get; set; } 
}

public class C3 
{   
    [Localizable]   
    public string L3 { get; set; }
}       

public static void Localize(object o, string cultureInfo)
{
    var t = o.GetType();
    if (t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(string))
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var property in t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        var pt = property.PropertyType;
        if (pt == typeof(string))
        {
            if (!Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(LocalizableAttribute)))
            {
                continue;
            }
            var localizedText = GetLocalizedText(property.GetValue(o, null).ToString(), cultureInfo);
            property.SetValue(o, localizedText, null);
            continue;
        }

        var value = property.GetValue(o, null);
        if (value == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (pt.IsArray)
        {
            foreach (var el in (object[])value)
            {
                Localize(el, cultureInfo);
            }
        }
        else if (pt.IsGenericType && pt.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        {
            foreach (var el in (IEnumerable)value)
            {
                Localize(el, cultureInfo);
            }
        }
        else if (pt.IsClass)
        {
            Localize(value, cultureInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `value` in your code and where does it come from?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, (bad copy and pasting!). Corrected

Comment: Now  `response` is missing.

Comment: 3rd time lucky.. Check now. Sorry about that

Comment: No problem, I also took `o` for response and it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. It could be made more succinct, but you will still need the logic, that you already implemented:

```
public static void Localize(object o, string cultureInfo)
{
    if (o != null)
    {
        foreach (var property in o.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            if (property.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(LocalizableAttribute)) != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(o, GetLocalizedText(property.GetValue(o, null).ToString(), cultureInfo), null);
            }
            else
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(o);
                if (value != null) 
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType.IsArray || (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)))
                    {
                        foreach (var el in (IEnumerable)value)
                        {
                            Localize(el, cultureInfo);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Localize(value, cultureInfo);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following example code as input is using the refactored method (ignore the `.Dump()` method - it's a [LINQPad extension](https://www.linqpad.net/)):

```
var c1 = new C1() { L1 = "L1" };
c1.C2Array = new C2[10];
c1.C2Array[0] = new C2() { L2 = "L2", C3 = new C3 { L3 = "L3" }, C3List = new List<C3> { new C3 { L3 = "ListL3" } } };
Localize(c1, "DE");
c1.Dump();
```

The outputs is the same as from your implementation:

[image]

As for the question if there is a better approach for localizing strings - it depends on your needs and conditions (and you did not show the implementation of the `GetLocalizedText` method - I can just make assumptions). If you have a WPF or Windows Forms or even a console application, then using [resource files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is much more easier to understand and implement [string translation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965329.aspx) (and no reflection is needed).

Comment: If there is a circular dependency between 2 classes this will trap in infinite loop, it's better to check for that as well